# Change application/target name in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5

I want to develop same app (same coding ) but with different names .So gone for renaming the app.I tried changing varoius parameters like `Bundle Name, Bundle Display Name, Product Name` and clean the app and then build it.`But build is succeeded` .After fraction of second my I see the status `Finished running 'appname' on iphone 6.0 simulator and my app stops` `running`.What should I exactly change to rename my app ?

Comment: 1. Clean simulator and run 2. Use different bundle identifier for both application target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bundle Display Name and Bundle Identifier.

The Bundle Display Name for the name that is displayed under the app icon on your device.
The Bundle Identifier to make the device, simulator and the app store understand that there are two different apps.

Comment: Thanks for the info.I have a small doubt.Where is config file in xcode.Is it .plist file generated automatically.And If I need to change themes ,app icons(display image )for diferent apps along with app name can I make it in info.plist file ????

Comment: You can do this in the YourAppName-Info.plist. For themes e.g. Images you just have to change the images. For further information google for multiple targets in iOS.

Comment: I mean I will get images and all of them from web services.Can I call them from info.plist file.writing xml parsing and so called methods.?

Comment: You have to add new targets and add the different file writing xml to different targets, then you can choose to build the explicit target. This is not so easy to explain you have to google it ;)

Answer (score 12):

Go to the project editor and select the target you want (will go blue)

[image]

Double click on the Target name in the target view window.

[image]

Type the new name

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that.  I checked on a recent Xcode and it still works for me.

Comment: Actually somehow my target name becomes empty "", and it is not allowing me to edit this name. If i create another new project and change the name.. then it is working.. but for my this project it is not working.. dont knw why

Comment: Sounds like the feature works correctly sometimes but you have discovered a bug.  I can't help you there, sorry.

Comment: Works for me Alex.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

change project name and click enter button.

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs can I know what is wildcard bundle identifier?

Comment: It is a Bundle Identifier with an asterix like de.yourcompany.*

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs Thanks for the info.I have a small doubt.Where is config file in xcode.Is it .plist file generated automatically.And If I need to change themes ,app icons(display  image )for diferent apps along with app name can I make it in info.plist file ????